# How do I use strings from a dll that does not use BorlndMM.dll

Tags: string, delphi, dll

I'm hooking a few functions from `DbkDebug240.bpl` into a IDE plugin.
The hooking works fine, but I need to use some string data.

The problem is that `DbkDebug*.bpl` does not use ShareMem; i.e. it does not import `BorlndMM.dll`. This causes problems because I'd like to call functions that return strings, but I cannot do this without causing exceptions.
I can 'fix' this by lying (i.e. use `PChar`), but then I get leaks.

example:

```
function GetExceptionMessage: Unicodestring; external 'Dbk240.bpl' 
   name '@Debug@TDebugger@GetExceptionMessage$qqrv';
//causes exceptions further down the line.

function GetExceptionMessage: PChar; external 'Dbk240.bpl' 
   name '@Debug@TDebugger@GetExceptionMessage$qqrv';
//I think this causes a leak futher down the line.
```

Is there a way to call functions that returns strings from a dll that does not use ShareMem in a way that does not leak?

The problem is that my plugin is in a DLL. I guess I can hook the DLL's memory manager's functions into those of the IDE, that would solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a package, you don't need to use ShareMem. Instead you link with runtime packages, making sure that you link to the rtl package. Because your code links to the rtl package, you naturally share the runtime, including the memory allocator.

> I guess I can hook the DLL's memory manager's functions into those of the IDE, that would solve the issue.

That seems to be the wrong way round. You just need to arrange that your DLL links against runtime packages.

Comment: dbkdebug cannot be included as a package. There is no .dcp file for it. So now I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: Do bear in mind that I cannot see any DLLs here. All I see is some functions from a package. I have no concept of what your programs structure is. I don't understand why you refer to a DLL when you are working with a package. Try to imagine things from our perspective. I have what can be seen on this page. What I can say is that packages share memory manager not using ShareMem but rather by sharing the use of the rtl package. So you should not have ShareMem anywhere.

Comment: Ok, so remove ShareMem everywhere and I should be good to go, because I have linked against the RTL package, even though my code is in a DLL. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe so. At that point when your DLL is loaded by the IDE it should link up to the rtl package already loaded in the IDE and it should all be good.